# Implement objects with several attributes in a lattice

Tags: types, ocaml, record

I need to represent a set of elements... As there is an **order** relation among these elements, I decide to use a **lattice** (instead of a list or a map...) to represent them, where the function `included` is used to check the order.

Each element has several attributes which represent their properties.

The 1) implementation is quite normal as follows:

```
module m = struct
  type t =
    | C0 | C1 | C2 ...

  let get_att0 (x: t) : string =
    | C0-> "C0"
    | C0-> "C1"
    | C0-> "C2"

  let get_att1 (x: t) : int =
    | C0-> 1
    | C0-> 2
    | C0-> 3

  let get_att2 (x: t) : bool =
    | C0-> true
    | C0-> false
    | C0-> true

  let included (x0: t) (x1: t) : bool =
    ...

end
```

The 2) implementation makes use of an internal type `record`:

```
module m = struct
  type t =
    | C0 | C1 | C2 ...

  type record =
    { att0: string; att1: int; att2: bool ... }

  let get_record (x: t) : record =
    | C0 -> { att0 = "C0"; att1 = 1; att2 = true ... }
    | C1 -> { att0 = "C1"; att1 = 2; att2 = false ... }
    | C2 -> { att0 = "C2"; att1 = 3; att2 = true ... }

  let get_att0 (x: t) : string =
    (get_record x).att0

  let get_att1 (x: t) : int =
    (get_record x).att1

  let get_att2 (x: t) : bool =
    (get_record x).att2

  let included (x0: t) (x1: t) : bool =
    ...

end
```

Could anyone tell me which implementation is more conventional, and more efficient in practice?

Comment: According to its title, the question is about objects. But they don't appear in the question. Moreover, you write a long paragraph about lattices and order, which correspond to the function `included` in your code, it is also the only function for which you don't provide the code... And when you provide a code, it is synctactically incorrect.

Comment: Well, the title, the code, and the syntax is only used to illustrate the core question... otherwise, they are secondary... I would hope you could give some constructive comments before down-voting the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, the implementation 1) would be used as in the second you are creating some workaround to write shorter but less clear code. Also, you are creating an intermediate struct that will be GCed just after being created so it's not very performant (don't know if ocaml will optimize this).

And if you want objects, there is that feature in OCaml: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual005.html .